# Flickering element on fixed sidebar on top scroll using offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop, flicker

I'm trying to create a fixed sidebar menu. Everything works fine but the sidebar element is flickering once you scroll to the top if you had scroll below.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var headerHeight = $('.js-site-header').outerHeight();
var sidebarThreeBlocks = (windowHeight-headerHeight)/3;
var sidebarTwoBlocks = (windowHeight-headerHeight)/2;
var sidebar = $('.js-sidebar');

$('.js-triple-nav a').css({height: sidebarThreeBlocks});
$('.js-double-nav a').css({height: sidebarTwoBlocks});

if (!!sidebar.offset()) {

$(window).scroll(function(){

    var stickyTopSidebar = sidebar.offset().top;
    var windowTop = ($(window).scrollTop())+headerHeight;

    if (stickyTopSidebar < windowTop) {
       sidebar.css({ top: windowTop });
    }
    else {
       sidebar.css({ top: '3.125em' });
    }

   });
  }
```

I used to put the `var stickyTopSidebar = sidebar.offset().top;` above with all the other variables but I would always get an error on the javascript console as it seemed the variable was undefined. Even so, the sidebar then worked perfectly, with no flickers but all the rest of javascript wouldn't work. Any hints or help?